# QML Button not clickable when TextField below it has focus on iOS

Tags: ios, qt, qml, qtquick2

QtQuick 2
I am trying to create a "clear" button for a TextField that appears over the TextField that, when clicked on, clears any text in the TextField.

Below is my main.qml file.  When run on desktop (both MacOS and Windows), you can click the "clear" or "X" button any time and it will clear the TextField.

**However**- on iOS the "clear" button does not appear to accept clicks while focus is on the TextField below it.  You can only use the button while you are not actively editing the TextField.  IE- If your focus is anywhere else, the "clear" button works.

**UPDATE**: When clicking on the "clear" button, it does visually look depressed when clicked.  But no `onClicked` action occurs.  Also, if I move the button to below the TextField instead of overtop of it - it does function.

How can I allow the clear button to function while focus is on the TextField below it?  Alternatively - is there another/easier way to create a TextField with a clear button similar to this?

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    TextField {
        id: searchField
        placeholderText: "Search..."
    }

    RoundButton {
        id: clearSearch
        anchors.right: searchField.right
        anchors.top: searchField.top
        anchors.bottom: searchField.bottom
        anchors.margins: 5
        text: "X"
        opacity: 0.5

        onClicked: {
            console.log("clear btn clicked");
            searchField.clear();
            searchField.forceActiveFocus();
        }
    }

}
```

Here is a screen shot of my TextField and "clear" button over it.
[image: TextField screen shot]

Comment: It looks like a bug, report it.

Comment: Yea, might be a bug. But for a workaround you could try set a `z` for the button

Comment: @Megued - Setting the 'z' seems to have no affect.

Comment: @eyllanesc- I added an update above, noting that the button (when overlapping the TextField) does actually visually depress when clicked on even though no onClicked action occurs.  So perhaps it is a bug.

Comment: @eyllanesc Reported as https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-81766